# Is there a better way to do this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently creating a navbar for mobile devices that will expand when the button is pressed. It expands a certain amount of pixels for the content. When the close button appears it should close back down to the original size of the button. It sizes up properly but will not resize down. Here is the basic version of my code.

I've tried creating variables and loads of other stuff that I honestly can't remember what exactly I have done.

My HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-background">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-navbar-button">
      <div class="bar-1">
      </div>
      <div class="bar-2">
      </div>
      <p class="closebtn">&times;</p>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.mobile-navbar-button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2vw;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 0;
}

.navbar-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.closebtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -80px;
  left: 35px;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.bar-1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: 37px;
}
.bar-2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 85px;
  left: 37px;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('width', '1425px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('height', '1200px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('left', '-400px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('top', '-400px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').find('.bar-1').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').find('.bar-2').css('display', 'none');
    $('.closebtn').css('display', 'block');
  });
  $(".closebtn").on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('width', '90px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('height', '90px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('left', '2vw');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css('top', '30px');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').find('.bar-1').css('display', 'block');
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').find('.bar-2').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

I would like the .mobile-navbar-button width and height to reflect back to 90px for the width and height. But currently this does not happen. The width and height sort of "sticks" at 1425px width and 1200px height and will not go back to what I have set up in .closebtn function.

Comment: You can set multiple CSS properties at once with `.css()`. See http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: Just a suggestion for code improvement, `$(".mobile-navbar-button")` should be kept in a variable and re-used.

Comment: Your `.closebtn` is an element inside `.mobile-navbar-button`. So it is likely that the moment you touch `.closebtn`, it also triggers your callback function for `.mobile-navbar-button`. You can stop the event propagation perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code somewhat simpler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('click touchstart', function() {
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css({
      "width": 1425 + "px",
      "height": 1200 + "px",
      "left": -400 + "px",
      "top": -400 + "px",
    });

    $('.mobile-navbar-button').find('.bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');

    $('.closebtn').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $(".closebtn").on('click touchstart', function() {
    $('.mobile-navbar-button').css({
      "width": 90 + "px",
      "height": 90 + "px",
      "left": 2 + "vw",
      "top": 30 + "px",
    });

    $('.mobile-navbar-button').find('.bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'block');
    $('.closebtn').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-navbar-button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2vw;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.closebtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -80px;
  left: 35px;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar-1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: 37px;
}

.bar-2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 85px;
  left: 37px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-background"></div>
<div class="mobile-navbar-button">
  <div class="bar-1">
  </div>
  <div class="bar-2">
  </div>
</div>
<p class="closebtn">&times;</p>
```

The **closebtn** had to be taken out of the **.mobile-navbar-button** element to get it to work correctly, and also its `click` / `touchstart` function had to be modified (a CSS **display hidden** added as the last line).

It works with `click` and `touchstart` events, and uses the `object` syntax for jQuery CSS.

It's usually a good idea to separate the unit from the number in jQuery CSS, because this way it may be used as a number instead of a string (**1425** is an **int**, but **1425px** is a **string**).

Comment: Thank you for your time on this issue! Your solution works great but not on mobile. I did finally find the reason and that is because when .mobile-navbar-button is clicked it is adding the css and then subtracting the bars but when the bars are gone the .mobile-navbar-button is not gone for what the code says so when you tap on it again it reruns the same code. I am about to work on a fix since i have an idea about what is going on. But thank you so much for your effort! I also did clean up my jQuery css thank you for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Proper way of using multile CSS
    $('#div').css({
        'width': '500px',
        'height': '500px',
        'background': '#eee',
        'border-top-left-radius': '40px',
        'display': 'none'
    });


    $('#close').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });


    $('#open').click(function () {
        $('#div').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        $('#close').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        $(this).css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });


    $('#close').click(function () {
        $('#div').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
        $('#open').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        $(this).css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
button {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 2vw;
    top: 5px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    z-index: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="open"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
  <button id="close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
  <div id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also showed the proper way of using multiple css. Hope that'd help.

Comment: You must explain what you have changed any why. For example why do you think it is required/relevant  to use `id` instead of `class` based selectors.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this issue! Your solution works great but not on mobile. I did finally find the reason and that is because when .mobile-navbar-button is clicked it is adding the css and then subtracting the bars but when the bars are gone the .mobile-navbar-button is not gone for what the code says so when you tap on it again it reruns the same code. I am about to work on a fix since i have an idea about what is going on. But thank you so much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work guys! A little bit of extra coding work around that may not be 100% practical but it works the way I want! Thank you for everyone for contributing! If you would like to see what I have done I will post it in this answer.

My HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-fullscreen-background">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-navbar-button">
      <div class="bar-1">
      </div>
      <div class="bar-2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-background">
      <p class="closebtn">&times;</p>
    </div>
```

I added the class navbar-background behind mobile-navbar-button so that the user would not be able to see it.

My CSS:

```
.mobile-navbar-button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2vw;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-background {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2vw;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-fullscreen-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: none;
}

.closebtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -80px;
  left: 35px;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.bar-1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: 37px;
}
.bar-2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 85px;
  left: 37px;
}
```

I then added navbar-background into the CSS and then gave mobile-navbar-button, navbar-fullscreen-background, and navbar-background a z-index to modify their stacking.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mobile-navbar-button").on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.navbar-background').css({'width': 1450 + 'px', 'height': 1200 + 'px', 'left': -400 + 'px', 'top': -400 + 'px',});
      $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').css('display', 'block');
        $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'none');
          $('.closebtn').css('display', 'block');
  });
  $(".closebtn").on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.navbar-background').css({'width': 90 + 'px', 'height': 90 + 'px', 'left': 2 + 'vw', 'top': 30 + 'px',});
      $('.mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1, .bar-2').css('display', 'block');
        $('.navbar-fullscreen-background').css('display', 'none');
          $('.closebtn').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

I finally took my jQuery (tidied up version) and fixed it to correspond correctly to my HTML and CSS changes and was able to make .mobile-navbar-button, .bar-1 and bar-2 display none so that instead will use the navbar-background as the grow and shrink area for the content.

Not 100% sure if it is the best way but it's a way that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

How come nobody has thought of just adding and removing a class to the nav button to signal state! manipulating style properties from JS/jQuery is horrible if you decide you want to change the applied styling. Just use a few extra CSS rules and toggle a class on the navbar. Much simpler and much easier to maintain

Simply toggle an `open` class on the navbarthe extra CSS will handle the display.

I've added the `click` event handlers to make a bit easier to use on devices without a touch screen ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navButton = $(".mobile-navbar-button");
  var closeButton = $(".closebtn");

  navButton.on('click', function() {
          navButton.toggleClass('open')
      });

  closeButton.on('touchstart', function() {
          navButton.toggleClass('open');
      });

});
```

```css
.mobile-navbar-button {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2vw;
  top: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 0;
}

.navbar-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.closebtn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -80px;
  left: 35px;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.bar-1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: 37px;
}

.bar-2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 54px;
  height: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 85px;
  left: 37px;
}

/* Change display when 'open' class is active on .mobile-navbar-button */
.mobile-navbar-button.open {
  height: 1200px;
  left: -400px;
  top: -400px;
}

.mobile-navbar-button.open .bar-1,
.mobile-navbar-button.open .bar-2 {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-navbar-button.open .closebtn {
  display: block;
  top: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-navbar-button">
  <div class="bar-1">
  </div>
  <div class="bar-2">
  </div>
  <p class="closebtn">&times;</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT** removed 'touchstart' event handlers